# How to get two TextView on to seperate lines?

Tags: android

I have few textviews and it looks like this now:
  ramdomName  10.20 - 11.30 Monday, tue

but i want ramdomName on new line and i want 10.20 on new line and also monday, tue on new line how do i do that?

This is code im using

```
  <LinearLayout

  android:id="@+id/widget38"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
android:orientation="horizontal"  >


     <TextView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/text1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:textSize= "30sp"  />

    <TextView
           android:id="@+id/text2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 


           android:textSize= "30sp"  />
    <TextView
           android:id="@+id/text6"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text=" - "
           android:textSize="30sp" 

             />

    <TextView
           android:id="@+id/text3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"


           android:textSize= "30sp"  />
    <TextView
           android:id="@+id/text6"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical"


           android:textSize= "30sp"  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this i have modified your code

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/widget38"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" - "
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Change android:orientation="horizontal" to android:orientation="vertical".